# Install Sphinx on FreeBSD

Tags: package, sphinx, freebsd

I know it sounds a bit like "google for me", but the articles Google gives me are related to 2007, 2009 and so on years, which is pretty obsolete. I couldn't find an instruction on sphinx official site either (only for other OS's).
Considering that, I would be really glad if someone could suggest me the way I can install the latest Sphinx on FreeBSD.
Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: Which sphinx do you mean exactly? Can you be more specific? Have you tried to follow the Linux instructions? They shouldn't be that much different.

Comment: What about using ports? `make -C /usr/ports/textproc/sphinxsearch install`? [textproc/sphinxsearch is currently 2.2.10, the last stable release](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=sphinxsearch&stype=all). Also available as a binary package (`pkg install sphinxsearch`) - but built with default options.